# Get updated session data in a Django Channels' consumer

Tags: django, websocket, session-variables, django-channels

Django Channels documentation says the following regarding session persistence:

> If you are in a WebSocket consumer, however, the session is populated but will never be saved automatically - you must call `scope["session"].save()`

However, I noticed that it doesn't work the other way aroung, e.g. if session data gets modified by a view, those changes don't affect the version of the session state accessible from inside a consumer (even with `request.session.modified = True` applied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While searching for the solution I found some unanswered questions discussing the same problem. And it doesn't seem to be covered in the docs (maybe it's mentioned somewhere, but I didn't manage to find it), so I decided to post my solution. Please comment if it's not correct for some reason.

For example, you want to get the updated session data inside `receive` method of an `AsyncWebsocketConsumer` child class.

```
class MyConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
async def receive(self, data):
   current_session_data = await sync_to_async ( self.scope["session"].load) ()
```

`load` returns a dict with all the session variables.
`self.scope["session"]` is not a dict, but it has `update` method which updates the underlying dict:

```
self.scope['session'].update( current_session_data )
await sync_to_async ( self.scope["session"].save ) ()
```

Hope this helps someone